# How to create java script files for MVC functionality

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have created a lot of java script functions to encapsulate crud operations for a kendo grid with the ability to edit data in a new page or a popup dialog. I am new to javascript. Is there a way to embed the grid and popup functionality into a script file. Right now i am using _partial views to and derived classes to do what I want.

Comment: Better you can use JS Library for your kick start. like JQuery,Dojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the base grid widget and then override the methods to create a new grid that's customized.

Like this...

```
var CustomGrid = kendo.ui.Grid.extend({

    // override the prototype or add custom methods here

});
```

Here is an article explaining more about how to do that:

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-16/inheriting_from_custom_widgets.aspx